# What is the best way to paste hundreds of characters per second in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

When I use send/sendinput/sendplay it takes too long to load, perhaps I am handling my strings improperly. I found the quickest route is to use the clipboard but even that is a problem because of how fast and diverse the amount of things are that I need to paste.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `SendInput`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) says:

> Under most conditions, SendInput is nearly instantaneous, even when sending long strings

There's a note, which won't be relevant though if you never run several AHK scripts simultaneously:

> If a script other than the one executing SendInput has a low-level keyboard hook installed, SendInput automatically reverts to SendEvent (or SendPlay if SendMode InputThenPlay is in effect)

However, I second that with some/many applications the clipboard method is indeed the only one actually instantaneous. So I just save [`ClipboardAll`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm#ClipboardAll) in a temporary variable and then restore it after copypasting the text.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of data is too large to paste at once, why not store the data into several variables (pseudo array) and loop through the pseudo array, copying  the first variable, to the clipboard, paste it, copy the second, etc. in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to the top of your script and try using the clipboard and SendInput again:

```
SetBatchLines, -1  
SetKeyDelay, -1, -1
```

And then there is `ControlSetText` which pretty much bypasses keyboard input emulation and communicates with the target process more directly. But you always replace the the whole text of that control, so it's not really just "pasting".

```
ControlSetText, Edit1, New Text Here, Untitled -
```

If you would tell what exactly you need to do we might be able to come up with a much better solution. [WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WinHttpObject5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#events) for example are extremely powerful functions/objects that can write to the RAM directly and send data to web servers directly, without shitty keyboard emulation. But since you haven't talked about what you are actually trying, it's hard to say if these would be of any use for you.

Also, be aware that your target process may have a limited buffer size of some sort so that you can't really paste more than x characters per second.